# Splitting course strings via regular expression

Tags: regex, string, plsql

Course names at Universities are generally split into 2 different parts, the "Department" and the "Course number"

ENGLISH 101, for example.

My goal, is to write a regex that matches the pattern, with groups that will allow me to specify whether I'm looking at the first half, or the second.

The problem, is that  not all universities use the same format for these things.  Below are the 3 test cases I have for "Weird stuff" that I've come across at other universities.

```
1250-101
ENGLISH101
ENG|101-L
```

I have written 2 regexes, one which handles all the weird numbers and odd characters, and one which handles the change from letters to numbers.   But I cannot figure out a way to make them play nicely with one another.   I've replicated them below.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ENGLISH101','(^\D*)(\d*)',1,1,NULL,1) FROM DUAL;
ENGLISH
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ENGLISH101','(^\D*)(\d*)',1,1,NULL,2) FROM DUAL;
101
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ENG|101-L','^(\w*)[\|/, \\-](.*)',1,1,NULL,1) FROM DUAL;
ENG
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('ENG|101-L','^(\w*)[\|/, \\-](.*)',1,1,NULL,2) FROM DUAL;
101-L
```

So that's good.  But I don't know how to combine to give me a single regex that will allow me to get ENGLISH (or whatever else there is) or 101 depending on grouping.   Or maybe the grouping is what's causing this headache to begin with?

Alternatively, has regex's been the wrong way to do this all along, and should I have just written a function to iterate through the strings character by character and split them myself?   It seems inefficient, but at this point I figure I should ask the question.

Any advice or insight into this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query below should select all the records corresponding to the three edge cases you described, and separate the first half from the second half of the course name.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '-') - 1) AS first_half,
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '-') + 1)    AS second_half
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%-%' AND col NOT LIKE '%|%'
UNION ALL
SELECT SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, '|') - 1),
       SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, '|') + 1)
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '%|%'
UNION ALL
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[0-9]', ''),
       REGEXP_REPLACE(col, '[A-Za-z]', '')
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%-%' AND col NOT LIKE '%|%'
```

**Explanation:**

The first query in the `UNION` targets those course names having a dash, but not a pipe.  In this case, we can cleanly split the name based on dash.  The second query targets names with a pipe (which can also have a dash).  In this case, we want to split on pipe.  Finally, the third query is the remaining case, which is an alphabetic course name immediately preceding, with no space, a course number.  For this, I used `REGEXP_REPLACE()` to remove either the numeric or alphabetical characters, to leave us with the first and second halves.

Note: If you have the edge cases together with the normal data, then you might have to tweak the `WHERE` conditions a bit.  For example, to target the third edge case `ENGLISH101`, you might check that it doesn't have any pipes or dashes, it has no whitespace, *and* it has both numbers and letters.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly, you're recommending using a variety of select statements (one per use case) which will only operate on rows formatted in a way they know how to parse, and then union those results together to get one result set?

Comment: @user3641364 That's exactly my strategy.  The thing is, to do this in a single regex would require, AFAIK, lookaheads or lookbehinds, which aren't supported anyway.  So using more basic string functions might be the only way.